# Find rows having a certain Week Number in a date using (Flask) SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, week-number

Using sqlalchemy, resp. flask_sqlalchemy and sqlite I would like to query
all rows which have the date field from last week. Best would even be where the
date column values are in a certain week of the year:

- `reporting_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, index=True)`

thinking of something like (pseudo code):

- **`found_rows = Table.query.filter_by(strftime('%W',reporting_date)==7).all()`**

Comment: `filter_by` is meant for simple equality checks. Use `filter` for more complex criterion.

Comment: Correct @IljaEverilä

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue.
My pseudo code was almost correct so here the working statement:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
DailyReportItem.query.filter(func.strftime('%W',DailyReportItem.reporting_date)=="07").all()
```

wich, in sqlite translates to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM daily_reports
WHERE strftime(?, daily_reports.reporting_date) = ?
('%W', '07')
```

the issue was basically only that Week Numbers have leading zeros and are Strings